# Font color not changing on hover

Tags: css, asp.net

I have been working on Asp menu and i want to set it's text color as white and change color when hover. But it seems not working for me.

My Asp menu code is this

```
<asp:Panel ID="MenuContainer" CssClass="Panel" runat="server">

                <asp:Menu ID="MainMenu" CssClass="StaticMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" RenderingMode="List"  StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False">
                    <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="DynamicMenuItem" />
                    <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="DynamicMenu" />
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="File" Value="File">
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Create User" Value="Create User"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="New Item2" Value="New Item2"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="New Item3" Value="New Item3"></asp:MenuItem>
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit" Value="Edit">
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="New Item1" Value="New Item1"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="New Item2" Value="New Item2"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="New Item3" Value="New Item3"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="New Item3" Value="New Item4"></asp:MenuItem>
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Permissions" Value="Permissions">
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="User Permission" Value="User Permission"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="New Item2" Value="New Item2"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="New Item3" Value="New Item3"></asp:MenuItem>
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                    </Items>
                    <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="StaticMenuItem"/>
                </asp:Menu>
            </asp:Panel>
```

My Css is this:

```css
#MenuContainer{
    height:70%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#264a60;
}

.StaticMenu{
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    Font-Size:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.StaticMenuItem{
     padding:5px;
}

.StaticMenuItem:hover{
    color:cyan;
}

.DynamicMenu{
    background-color:white;
    display:block;
}

.DynamicMenuItem{
    padding:5px;
    width:200px;
}

.DynamicMenuItem:hover{
    color:red;
}
```

[image]
I don't know from where but menu's text is picking blue color instead of white. Am i missing something...???

Sample code

```
<div id="MenuContainer" class="Panel">


                <a href="#MainMenu_SkipLink" style="position:absolute;left:-10000px;top:auto;width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden;">Skip Navigation Links</a><div class="StaticMenu" id="MainMenu">
            <ul class="level1">
                <li><a class="level1 StaticMenuItem" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;MainMenu&#39;,&#39;File&#39;)">File</a><ul class="level2 DynamicMenu">
                    <li><a class="level2 DynamicMenuItem" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;MainMenu&#39;,&#39;File\\Create User&#39;)">Create User</a></li><li><a class="level2 DynamicMenuItem" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;MainMenu&#39;,&#39;File\\New Item2&#39;)">ghhsvdhh</a></li><li><a class="level2 DynamicMenuItem" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;MainMenu&#39;,&#39;File\\New Item3&#39;)">New Item3</a></li>
                </ul></li><li><a class="level1 StaticMenuItem" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;MainMenu&#39;,&#39;Edit&#39;)">Edit</a><ul class="level2 DynamicMenu">
                    <li><a class="level2 DynamicMenuItem" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;MainMenu&#39;,&#39;Edit\\New Item1&#39;)">New Item1</a></li><li><a class="level2 DynamicMenuItem" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;MainMenu&#39;,&#39;Edit\\New Item2&#39;)">New Item2</a></li><li><a class="level2 DynamicMenuItem" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;MainMenu&#39;,&#39;Edit\\New Item3&#39;)">New Item3</a></li><li><a class="level2 DynamicMenuItem" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;MainMenu&#39;,&#39;Edit\\New Item4&#39;)">New Item3</a></li>
                </ul></li><li><a class="level1 StaticMenuItem" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;MainMenu&#39;,&#39;Permissions&#39;)">Permissions</a><ul class="level2 DynamicMenu">
                    <li><a class="level2 DynamicMenuItem" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;MainMenu&#39;,&#39;Permissions\\User Permission&#39;)">User Permission</a></li><li><a class="level2 DynamicMenuItem" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;MainMenu&#39;,&#39;Permissions\\New Item2&#39;)">New Item2</a></li><li><a class="level2 DynamicMenuItem" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;MainMenu&#39;,&#39;Permissions\\New Item3&#39;)">New Item3</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            </ul>
        </div><a id="MainMenu_SkipLink"></a>

    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating anchor tags. Your default text color for anchors is the default browser blue. You can override this with some css.

```
#MenuContainer a, li a {
  color: #fff;
}

#MenuContainer a:hover, li a:hover {
  color: #0ff;
}
```

Comment: hover is working fine but normal text color is not working..How can i set that....????

Comment: You can either use the keyword `!important` to override all other css or you can use proper selectors to find the specific anchor tags in just that menu and the normal `color` property will work. If you will post the sample output instead of an image I can help you figure out the selector you need.

Comment: Load the page, right-click in your browser, select View Source, and paste it into Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am sorry DunningKrugerEffect but i am new to all this that's why i don't know that much.

Comment: Find the div with an ID of MenuContainer and paste everything inside that div into Stack Overflow. When you load the page and select View Source you will see something like `<div id="MenuContainer">`. There may also be some ASP junk in the ID.

Comment: I have added sample output in my question.

Comment: Thanks a lot...it's working now..can i give my dynamic menu items a different color.????

Comment: Make the `li a` and `li a:hover` selectors their own css block to give them different colors.

Comment: It's not working. By making 'li a' and 'li a:hover' it's changing color of normal menu items too.

Comment: You can add a class specifically to those links if you only want to change those links.